# OrderBy multiple properties in Razor and Umbraco 4.11.8

Tags: linq, razor, sql-order-by, umbraco, multiple-columns

During an update of our website with Umbraco, we upgraded from 4.7.2 to 4.11.8.

In a CSHTML-File I had this code:

```
foreach(var item in Model.AncestorOrSelf("Master")
                         .Items.First()
                         .PublicationFolder.First()
                         .Children.Where("Visible")
                         .OrderBy("publicationType, date desc"))
```

It worked fine and sorted the collection first by *publicationType* and then by the newest *date*.

In the new version (4.11.8) it doesn't work anymore. It gives me an exception: `At least one object must implement IComparable.`

And if I write `.OrderBy("publicationType", "date desc")`, it doesn't affect the collection.

So is this a bug or am I doing anything wrong?
Is there a workaround?

Comment: Yes I found a solution. I will write an answer for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution so I need to cast the collection to a `List<DynamicNode>` so that it works.

```
foreach (var item in ((List<DynamicNode>)@Model.AncestorOrSelf("Master")
    .Items.First()
    .PublicationFolder.First()
    .Children.Where("Visible").Items)
    .OrderBy(t => t.GetPropertyValue("publicationType"))
    .ThenByDescending(t => t.GetPropertyValue("date")))
```

Comment: Brian, actually that's almost exactly the same as mine answer. We are casting the same things, the only difference being that you are doing an implicit cast, and I am casting using the Cast<T>() method.

Answer (score 1):

The `Where("Visible")` extension returns `IQueryable<DynamicNode>` so you should be able to apply the LINQ `OrderBy()` and `OrderByDescending()` syntax for this query. You may need to alter certain bits though:

```
foreach(var item in Model.AncestorOrSelf("Master")
                     .Items.First()
                     .PublicationFolder.First()
                     .Children.Where("Visible")
                     .Cast<DynamicNode> // This line is optional
                     .OrderBy(x => x.GetPropertyValue("publicationType")
                     .ThenByDescending(x => x.GetPropertyValue("date"))
```

I have included an optional line to show that you can explicitly cast the `dynamic` objects to `DynamicNode` objects and you can then use intellisense in your view.

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves you should be able to chain the OrderBys

```
foreach(var item in Model.AncestorOrSelf("Master").Items.First().PublicationFolder.First().Children.Where("Visible").OrderBy("publicationType").OrderByDescending("date"))
```

Comment: It could be the solution, but I'm getting this error: _'umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeList' does not contain a definition for 'OrderByDescending'_. Is there anything missing?

Comment: Chaining the ordering seems to override it with each part of the chain, so this has a limited use-case and doesn't solve the original question.  For me the other solutions (using `.ThenByDescending`) below worked better as I needed to order by several different properties concurrently, which is the crux of the question too.  Good to know you can chain like this though, so thanks for this answer :)